# Why can't push my wordpress directory into remote github repository?

Tags: git, github, push

Target :to push /var/www/html/wp in to newstart in remote github repository.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

The ssh and github were in good status.

In remote

1.To create a new project named `newstart` in github web page.

In local

2.cd  /var/wwww/html/wp
3.sudo git init
4.git add *
5.git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Thank to ffledgling,two commands added.

```
git commit -m "First commit" 
git remote add origin git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git 

git push origin master 
To git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git 
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git' 
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do 
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes 
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How to push /var/www/html/wp into remote github repository now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't git commit.
2. You didn't tell git what `origin` means. You'll have to :

   ```
   $ git remote add origin remote repository URL
   ```

See instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the repo at github first: 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: Notice this: "To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with README, license, or gitignore files. You can add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub." Probably you have the README.md or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

1.git push -f origin master 
To solve the problem:`failed to push some refs to...`  with -f parameter in git push command.
2. to change **sudo git init** into **git init**
Why change **sudo git init** into **git init**?

If .git was created by **sudo git init**,there will be permission problem for **git push -f origin master**.

```
ls -al .
total 204
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 Jan  1 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root      4096 Dec 12 22:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root      4096 Jan  1 21:02 .git
```

If .git was created by **git init**,there **will not** be permission problem for **git push -f origin master**.

```
ls -al .
total 204
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 Jan  1 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root      4096 Dec 12 22:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 debian8  debian8   4096 Jan  1 21:02 .git
```

The ownership of .git directory will prevent executing **git push -f origin master**.

Well done now.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git+ssh://git@github.com/someone/newstart.git' 
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do 
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes 
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The above error says that you currently are not in sync with the remote repository.

**Sync**

```
git pull --rebase
```

**Now Push**

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

> If the push still does not work saying that remote does not exists. Add it.

```
git remote add origin <path/to/your/remote/repo>
```